# Dynamically cache images in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, last-modified

I'm developing some kind of landing page with heavy images. 
I've cached images on client side using following code in web.config

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires"/>
</staticContent>
```

Sometimes users, are cropping or re-sizing their images, but browser still shows cached images.
Is there any way, I can force tell that image was changed on server, and all browsers should refresh cache.

I guess I need use LastModified HTTP header, but I have no idea how to set this header to static image in ASP .NET MVC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of caching on the client-side is to not check again for a new version for some defined period of time. In this sense, adding a last modified header doesn't help you because the browser won't request the file to get that header. Typically, the method of handling static resources is to set a far future expires, such that the resource will be cached client-side near indefinitely, and then altering the resource name in some way when there's a new version. If the name of the resource changes, then the browser will automatically fetch it again, because it doesn't have a resource with that name.

I'm not sure how your users are doing things, but if you're cropping or resizing images, it's typical to give the image a new name at the same time. For example, the original might be `original.jpg`, a 200x200 crop might be `original_200x200.jpg`, etc.

Short of that, you can employ a cache-busting querystring to force the browser to re-request the resource. Simply doing something like appending the last modified date as a timestamp is usually quite effective. For example, instead of referencing the image as `image.jpg`, you reference it as `image.jpg?1416417459`. Once the image is modified, the timestamp would be different and would be treated by the browser as an entirely new resource.

Comment: Thank's Chris for such amazing answer